# Proof verification for independence using characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ be independent random vectors. We need to show that for $s=(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)^T$, $s_1X_1+s_2X_2$ and $s_3Y_1+s_4Y_2$ are independent. 
Proof: Let $W=(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$. Then the characteristic function of $W$ is
\begin{align}
E(e^{it^TW})& =E(e^{i(t_1X_1+t_2X_2+t_3Y_1+t_4Y_2)})\\
&= E(e^{i(t_1X_1+t_2X_2)}e^{i(t_3Y_1+t_4Y_2)}) \\
& = E(e^{i(t_1X_1+t_2X_2)})E(e^{i(t_3Y_1+t_4Y_2)}) \text{ by independence of $X$ and $Y$}.\end{align}
Now, consider the characteristic function of the vector $W_1=(s_1X_1+s_2X_2,s_3Y_1+s_4Y_2)$.
\begin{align}
E(e^{it^TW_1})& =E(e^{i(t_1(s_1X_1+s_2X_2)+t_2(s_3Y_1+s_4Y_2))})\\
&= E(e^{i(t_1s_1X_1+t_1s_2X_2)}e^{i(t_2s_3Y_1+t_2s_4Y_2)}) \\
& = E(e^{it_1(s_1X_1+s_2X_2)})E(e^{it_2(s_3Y_1+s_4Y_2)}) \text{ by independence of $X$ and $Y$}.\end{align}
Thus, $s_1X_1+s_2X_2$ and $s_3Y_1+s_4Y_2$ are independent.
I need to prove this for higher dimensions, but it seems it would be a direct extension of the above. Can someone please verify the above proof. I am unable to find the proof of the statement anywhere in the website, but it seems to be intuitive. Also, it would be great if anyone suggests any reference to study the multivariate independence. Thanks!

Comment: Measurable functions of independent random variables are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Two random vectors $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ are independent iff for every $A\in\sigma(X)$ and every $B\in\sigma(Y)$ we have: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Here: $\sigma(X)=\{\{X\in B\}\mid B\in\mathcal B^2\}$ where $\mathcal B^2$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^2$.

If $f,g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ are Borel-measurable function then:$$\sigma(f(X))=\{\{f(X)\in B\}\mid B\in\mathcal B\}=\{\{X\in f^{-1}(B)\}\mid B\in\mathcal B\}\subseteq\sigma(X)$$and similarly: $$\sigma(g(Y))\subseteq\sigma(Y)$$

So if $A\in\sigma(f(X))$ and $B\in\sigma(g(Y))$ then $A\in\sigma(X)$ and $B\in\sigma(Y)$ so that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

This tells us that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

Apply this on the functions $f,g$ prescribed by $(u,v)\mapsto s_1u+s_2v$ and $(u,v)\mapsto s_3u+s_4u$ respectively.